# remote: GitLab: Push operation timed out

Tags: git, gitlab, bfg-repo-cleaner

I'm trying to fix my repository with BFG Repo-Cleaner, by removing some large files that were added to it, using this guide: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/.
When I'm trying to push (a very large push), I'm getting: "remote: GitLab: Push operation timed out".

The output I receive when pushing consists of the following:

```
numerating objects: 12176, done.
Writing objects: 100% (12176/12176), 4.15 MiB | 3.89 MiB/s, done.
Total 12176 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 12176
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8566/8566), done.
remote: GitLab: Push operation timed out
remote:
remote: Timing information for debugging purposes:

remote: Running checks for ref: feature/XXXXXX1
remote: Running checks for ref: hotfix/XXXXXXX2
remote: Running checks for ref: hotfix/XXXXXXX3
remote: Running checks for ref: hotfix/XXXXXXX4
remote: Running checks for ref: main
remote: Running checks for ref: sandbox/XXXXXXX5
remote: Running checks for ref:
remote: Running checks for ref:
remote: Running checks for ref:
remote: Running checks for ref:
remote: Running checks for ref:
```

Followed by:

```
[remote rejected]   refs/merge-requests/115/head -> refs/merge-requests/115/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
 ! [remote rejected]   refs/merge-requests/115/merge -> refs/merge-requests/115/merge (deny updating a hidden ref)
 ! [remote rejected]   refs/merge-requests/116/head -> refs/merge-requests/116/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
 ! [remote rejected]   refs/merge-requests/116/merge -> refs/merge-requests/116/merge (deny updating a hidden ref)
 ! [remote rejected]   refs/merge-requests/117/head -> refs/merge-requests/117/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
 ! [remote rejected]   refs/merge-requests/117/merge -> refs/merge-requests/117/merge (deny updating a hidden ref)
```

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Every message that starts with `remote:` is coming, not from your own `git push`, but rather from some software *on* the remote (i.e., on the GitLab server). Therefore any problems here have to be fixed *on* the remote, i.e., on the GitLab server, or else somehow avoided from your end. In your particular case the latter is probably not possible. The `timing information` printed here is probably meant for the *administrator of the GitLab software*, i.e., you should forward this to your GitLab support people and ask *them*.

Comment: Hi, thank you! 
I'll contact GitLab support about it and see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab no longer supports using BFG and now [supports `git filter-repo`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html#purge-files-from-repository-history)

In previous versions of GitLab, the repository cleanup supported using the BFG object map.

The current recommended procedure is

- Export the project
- From the bundle, bare mirror clone to a fresh repository
- Run the cleanup, using `git filter-repo`
- Force push the heads, tags, and replace refs
- Wait 30 minutes
- Run the Repository Cleanup using the commit-map in `.git/filter-repo/`

Then the cleanup process will remove all of the dereferenced files or commits.